# Преобразовать строку с числами и буквами в число

Tags: xcode, swift, objective-c

Здравствуйте, ребята, помогите!

Нужно `"123текст"(String)` преобразовать в `123(Int)`.
Закономерно, что в начале идут цифры, а потом только текст.

Количество цифр в строке >= n.

У   js есть похожая функция `parseInt()`.

Не подскажите, как в swift это сделать, ну или objC?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = NSString(string: "123text").intValue //123
var y = "123text".toInt() //nil
```

Comment: А если будет

    var x = NSString(string: "123text456").intValue

то что вернет intValue? 123 или 123456?