# Является ли строка числом

Tags: swift

Как определить, является ли переменная String Числои? В Delphi есть подобная функция TryStrToFloat.

Простенький пример:

```
var t:String = "1234,41"

    if (Является ли t чисолом типа Double) {
        Println("Это число!")
    } else {
        Println("Не число")
    }
```

Comment: Такой вариант есть: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/370570/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE

Comment: Думаю, что аналогично и с даблом можно

Comment: Да, есть: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031621/swift-how-to-convert-string-to-double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо уже нашел решение.

```
func isDouble(text:String) -> Bool {
        guard let _ = Double(text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: ".")) else { return false }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы определить является ли строка числом, надо сделать итерацию по строке, взять каждый символ при помощи characterAtIndex(_:) и проверить является ли он цифрой (ну или допустить присутствие одной точки для дробных).

В комментариях предложили несколько более простых способов, например `string.integerValue`. это не совсем верно, поскольку любая строка при конвертации в число вернет 0. так же не учтены варианты такие как '123abc' вернет '123', хотя строка не является числом (строка '123abc456' тоже вернет '123').